# Need to bold one line of text using CSS and the div id tag

Tags: css, html

I am working on my resume and am trying to bold the name of my degree....'aint workin! Any help would be appreciated.... Here is my html:

```
<section>
   <h4>Education</h4>
   <div id="edccDegree">Associate of Technical Arts</div> 
   Web Application Development</div>
   Edmonds Community College, August 2013<br>
   GPA: 3.3 out of 4.0<br>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#edccDegree {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Please balance your HTML tags... Anyway I put your code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKuZJ/) and it works well to me. [Are you using IE7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343781/padding-not-working-when-using-section-tag-in-ie)?

Comment: What's with that extra closing div at `Web Application Development</div>`?

Comment: That extra `</div>` could cause some browsers to choke.

Comment: opening div tag is missing in the 4th line..Why you are using div and then bold style for that.Directly you can use <b></b> tags.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I took out the extra closing div tag but still having a problem. I don't want to use any formatting in the html, only in the css......still not working

Comment: Despite the syntax errors, the code actually makes the degree title appear in bold. That is, the code posted does not reproduce the problem, and the cause is in the part of the page that was not disclosed. You are not using one of the infamous “CSS Reset” codes, are you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
<h4>Education</h4>
<b>Associate of Technical Arts</b> 
<div>Web Application Development</div>
Edmonds Community College, August 2013<br>
GPA: 3.3 out of 4.0<br>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wrapping that line in a div? Divs are really structural elements rather than text formatting elements. A strong tag should do what you require unless you have removed that styling already.

```
<section>
    <h4>Education</h4>
    <strong>Associate of Technical Arts</strong><br> 
    Web Application Development<br>
    Edmonds Community College, August 2013<br>
    GPA: 3.3 out of 4.0<br>
```

Comment: I thought I had to wrap it in a div tag to format it in CSS. I thought about using <strong> but am trying to avoid any formatting in the html.

Comment: Adding a `strong` tag best conveys the meaning that you are giving to that text. You are wishing to convey emphasis to that text so semantically that is an ideal choice. Divs are better for layout than simply text formatting.